# Skip subfolder if path contains a string

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA excel macro to search and copy files from a folder and any subfolder to another folder and it works correctly (you can find it below).

```
Sub Cloud_SII()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call Pulisci_fogli
Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim HostFolder As String
HostFolder = "O:\EE\Flussi Del. 65-12\Cloud_SII"
Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
End Sub

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
Dim SubFolder, File
For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
DoFolder SubFolder
For Each File In Folder.Files
If DateDiff("d", File.DateLastModified, Date) < 1 And File.Name Like "*zip*" Then
File.Copy "O:\EE\Flussi Del. 65-12\Cloud_SII_Smistatore\"
End If
Next
End Sub
```

I'd like to add a filter on the folders in which the macro search. I want to skip any subfolder whom path contains the string "2017" or "2G" but the string is not the last part of the path, see the example below:

```
O:\EE\Flussi Del. 65-12\Cloud_SII\TME\2017\1111
O:\EE\Flussi Del. 65-12\Cloud_SII\2G\2018\0103
```

Is there a way to make the code just skip the paths that contains those strings?

Comment: Check your folder names with VBA-`INSTR`-[function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264811(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: Got it! I just added "If InStr(1, SubFolder, "2G", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, SubFolder, "2017", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then GoTo Prossima" and it worked perfectly!  Thanks IQV!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the VBA-function `INSTR` ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264811(v=office.14).aspx)) and check if your folder names contain these strings:

```
If InStr(1, SubFolder, "2G", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or 
   InStr(1, SubFolder, "2017", vbTextCompare) Then ...
```